# How do I copy key value pair references from one map to another map of the same type?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl

I have two maps in C++ of type `std::map < std::string , std::vector < std::set< std::string>::iterator>>`.

1. `catalog`
2. `duplicatesCatalog`

I would like to insert the reference of elements of `catalog(key,value)` into `duplicatesCatalog` on a scenario where the size of the vector of iterators in catalog is greater than 2.

How do I do it?

Comment: standard containers do not accept reference template parameters because standard containers require the types to be movable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `std::reference_wrapper` for parameters of `duplicatesCatalog`.